# react native) calling OnPress multiple functions and parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a real native app with redux
I try to save the values entered in both textinput to redux store by pressing 'insert' button.
Attempt to insert several redux functions using Onpress in 'insert' Button.
But I don't know how to deliver a number of functions and parameters to Onpress.

I'm trying to code in this way. But I got a error

```
<Button title="insert" onPress={(name, dosage) => {
    this.props.inputName(this.state.name)
    this.props.inputDosage(this.state.dosage)
  }
} />
```

And this is whole code.

```
class Add extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            dosage: 0
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Title>Add Medication</Title>
                <SubTitle>Step 1. Medication Information</SubTitle>
                <Descript>1. What is the name of the medication?</Descript>
                <TextBox
                    placeholder="Name"
                    style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                />
                <Descript>2. What is the dosage?(Optional)</Descript>
                <TextBox
                    placeholder="e.g. 2"
                    onChangeText={(dosage) => this.setState({ dosage })}
                />
                <Condition>Should be numeric</Condition>
                <Button title="Next" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail")} />

                <Button title="insert" onPress={(name, dosage) => {
                    this.props.inputName(this.state.name)
                    this.props.inputDosage(this.state.dosage)
                    }
                } />
                <Text>{this.props.state.name}</Text>
                <Text>{this.props.state.dosage}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I want your help. Thank you :)

Comment: You have added the `mapDispatchToProps` to your component or the parent of your component, right?

Comment: sure. I added `mapStateToProps`, `matchDispatchToProps` function and connected like this : `export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Add);`

Comment: if you add your redux codes as well, I can check it from there as well. In the given codes, I couldnt see any error or mistake